# How do I read a 'family' of h5 files using python?

Tags: file, hdf5, python-3.6

These are files in the file system as:

```
vgg16_weights_tf_dim_ordering_tf_kernels_0.h5
vgg16_weights_tf_dim_ordering_tf_kernels_1.h5
vgg16_weights_tf_dim_ordering_tf_kernels_2.h5
vgg16_weights_tf_dim_ordering_tf_kernels_3.h5
vgg16_weights_tf_dim_ordering_tf_kernels_4.h5
vgg16_weights_tf_dim_ordering_tf_kernels_5.h5
```

an attempt to open '`vgg16_weights_tf_dim_ordering_tf_kernels_0.h5`' causes an error that suggests Family driver should be used

opening with

```
f = h5py.File('../input/keras-models/vgg16_weights_tf_dim_ordering_tf_kernels_0.h5','r', driver='family')
```

> causes error "file name not unique"

opening with

```
f = h5py.File('../input/keras-models/vgg16_weights_tf_dim_ordering_tf_kernels_%d.h5','r', driver='family')
```

> causes error "Unable to open file (Family member size should be 102400000.  but the size from file access property is 2147483647)"

Comment: answering my own question:

The correct call is:

f = h5py.File('../input/keras-models/vgg16_weights_tf_dim_ordering_tf_kernels_%d.h5','r', driver='family', memb_size=102400000)

Answer (score 3):

After some research I found the right way of opening a family of files as:

h5py.File('../input/keras-models/vgg16_weights_tf_dim_ordering_tf_kernels_%d.h5','r', driver='family', memb_size=102400000)

The default memb_size is 2**31-1 (i.e. 2147483647). If file family is written with member size specified as 102400000, one should also open it with the same.